# Ray for gameobject unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, raycasting

Not sure if it is possible to use Ray for a gameobject in unity, it's possible for mouse click but if it's not possible for a gameobject how to replicate the results?

Need the following code to work in the same way by for the ray to take in the players position and not mouse click.

```
 // Get the place the player has clicked
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        // Holds information regarding the mouseclick
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        // Now work out if we fire or not
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
        {
            if(hitInfo.distance < maxRange)
            {
                FireAtPoint(hitInfo.point);
```

Have tried to do the following although it doesn't give the correct location and gives a different location instead when the player is static.

```
// Holds information regarding the mouseclick
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        // Now work out if we fire or not
        if (Physics.Raycast(player.transform.position,transform.forward, out hitInfo))
        {
```

Comment: Let me guess: your game is not from a first person perspective.

Comment: Not it's not :) Gets more fun with parabolic firing and stuff tho, which is the issue of trying to work out to replace ray for enemy AI @Draco18s

Answer (score 0):

`player.transform.position` will fire from the player's position, but `transform.forward` is going to be "forward" for whatever your script is attached to in relation to it's origin rotation.

If it's not firing in the direction you intend, then you are probably meaning to write `player.transform.forward` or "forward" for whatever your script is attached to is not the forward you think it is.

Comment: Am aware of that and solve it using .LookAt() but it still doesn't go to the intended location and will always overshoot the player - yet the first option works perfectly - just need to replicate it with the 2nd way.

Comment: in which case it sounds like the origin location/rotation of `player` is not where you expect it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue lay from the position(origin) that I was firing from,

```
// Holds information 
    RaycastHit hitInfo;

    // Now work out if we fire or not
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position,transform.forward, out hitInfo))
    {
```